# React ref: How to get ref from a child component to use in parent component

Tags: reactjs, ref

Is there any easier way to get ref from a child component and use it in the parent component without going down to deep in the nested components?

Imagine you have a parent component and the targeted child is like 5 level down. Then I have to access it like this from the parent component.

```
this.myRef.current.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking into `context` - https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html.